# python package office365 installation crashes os on pqy5 dependency installation

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, office365

I Noticed this behaviour 2 times, but this package installation is literally leaking memory and crashing the OS.

Any approach how to solve this ?

```
pip install office365
```

[image: Mac OS memory raising like crazy]

Comment: It's only 20 GB... :P

Comment: Have you tried it with a different v of python? 3.9?

Comment: yes, all versions are affected. In the answer that is active now, you can understand the problem. There is another package with the same name, retired one, that made the confusion in loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, the person that initially create [office365](https://pypi.org/project/office365/) package retired the [project](https://github.com/matthewgdv/office)

The proper or I should say mostly trusted on github office and sharepoint between others clients for python is [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/) , but behind this strangely long package name, the package in import is still  registered with name  "office365" . So if you use the latest library, it is more regularly update and you might get what you expect. I do not have the strange dependency and memory leak error there, hence will give answer to this one.

So, use this command to avoid problems:

```
pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client
```